# dbms_scheduler Create Job Not running Job

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to run a procedure through a dbms_scheduler but it is just getting created but not running. DataBase Version Used Oracle 11.2.x

**Procedure**

```
create or replace procedure count_comp
as
Total_count number;
begin
select count(*) into Total_count from user_tables;
dbms_output.put_line('Number   '|| Total_count);
end;
```

**Create Job**

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        job_name => 'My_Count_Job',
        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
        job_action => 'count_comp',
        start_date => '28-APR-08 07.00.00 PM Asia/Calcutta',
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2', /* every other day */
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        enabled =>TRUE,
        comments => 'My new job');
END;
/
```

Comment: Do you know for sure it is not running, or were you expecting its output to have appeared somewhere?  The output will never be seen by anyone.

Comment: @Tony Andrews yes we can check through select * from dba_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOGS.

Comment: Please try running this and post the output: `SELECT job_name, enabled, state, start_date FROM user_scheduler_jobs
where job_name = 'My_Count_Job';`

Comment: It would not hurt if your procedure was valid. you might as well fix your procedure's errors: `user_table` should be `user_tables`.`putline` should be `put_line`.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the possible Reasons as mentioned below. 
job_queue_processes may be too low 
To check Execute below query
select value from v$parameter where name='job_queue_processes';

Then check the number of running jobs

```
select count(*) from dba_scheduler_running_jobs;
select count(*) from dba_jobs_running;
```

If this is the problem you can increase the parameter using

```
alter system set job_queue_processes=1000;
```

2) max_job_slave_processes may be too low
If this parameter is not NULL then it limits how many dbms_scheduler jobs can
be running at a time. To check w

```
select value from dba_scheduler_global_attribute
where attribute_name='MAX_JOB_SLAVE_PROCESSES';
```

Then check the number of running jobs

```
select count(*) from dba_scheduler_running_jobs;
```

If this is the problem you can increase the number or just NULL it out using

```
exec dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('max_job_slave_processes',null)
```

3) sessions may be too low

4) Check if  the Scheduler been disabled

```
select value from dba_scheduler_global_attribute where attribute_name='SCHEDULER_DISABLED'
```

If this query returns TRUE then you can fix this using
SQL> `exec dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('scheduler_disabled','false');`

Comment: Job_queue_processes was 0 so I altered it and it worked . Thanks @nitin.sharma0180 for your time and answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT JOB_NAME, STATE FROM DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS WHERE JOB_NAME = 'partition_table_plapp2';
```

Above query will tell you status of your Job : ENABLED, DISABLED, SCHEDULED

```
select JOB_NAME, STATUS, ERROR#, ADDITIONAL_INFO from ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS where job_name = 'partition_table' ;
```

Above query will tell you what went wrong while running your job.

Once you find what is the issue with your job we can investigate further.

If you are using sqldeveloper (sql developer) to create and schedule DBMS_SCHEDULER (dbms scheduler) jobs, I would advice you go through this page : http://www.opencodez.com/oracle/oracle-job-scheduler-guide-examples-part-1.htm