# Scheduler job stuck on running oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have this scheduler made on Oracle pl/SQL that deletes old users from the database every 5 years.
I tried testing it by changing the time period from 5 years to 1 min (and starting date to five minutes after insert), it stucks on running and doesn't complete the job unless the scheduler gets stopped.
How can this be fixed? I tried using commit after the delete statement with no results.

Here's the code:

```
BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
   job_name   => 'Delete_Idle_Users',
   job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action => 'BEGIN
     DELETE FROM Store_Member
     WHERE Member_ID IN (
       Select Member_ID
       FROM (
         select Member_ID, Max(Purchase_Date) AS Last_Purchase
         From Cart
         Group By Member_ID
       ) 
       WHERE Last_Purchase<(SYSDATE-(365.25*5))
     );
   END;',
   start_date => TO_DATE('01-GEN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY'),
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=YEARLY',
   enabled    => TRUE,
   comments   => 'Deleting users that didn't buy anything in 5 years.'
 );
END;
```

Comment: Your code cannot run any job, because it has at least two issues. 1) You need to escape single quotes inside string by doubling them (`'this is a string with '' quote'`) or by using [q-notation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/literal.htm#LNPLS01326) like `q'$this is a string with ' quote$'`. This issue is in the job comment parameter. 2) As far as I know month `GEN` does not exist. You've used it as starting point. So please, provide a working code that you have run.

Comment: Does the block run on the command line? I'm wondering if it's a performance issue or a scheduler issue. The innermost subquery looks rather inefficient, as you first aggregate the entire cart history and then filter the results, rather than filtering first.

Comment: By the way, `sysdate-(365.25*5)` uses an approximation of a year length, which might be  out by a day. You might look at `add_months(last_purchase, -12)`.

Comment: Try to use `/` at the end of PL/SQL block.

Comment: @astentx 'GEN' is Italian for 'JAN', but I agree language-dependant month names are better avoided and it would be better written as `date '2021-01-01'`. I've seen production failures due to this kind of thing.

Comment: If it's not a performance issue, perhaps a row is locked by another session and the delete statement is just waiting. It would be worth checking what it is actually doing while it's running and nothing seems to be happening. Oracle is pretty well instrumented - you could start by querying [v$session](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SESSION.html).

Comment: I've missed `enabled = TRUE` so deleted comment on it. If so, there is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45844246/dbms-scheduler-create-job-not-running-job). You should check`job_queue_processes` init parameter.

Comment: @William Robertson Thank you! Using commit after INSERTING the rows and at the end of the delete statement in the job seems to have fixed the issue; regarding the inefficiency of the delete, this was just an exercise so the rows number is very low (less than 1000) and for this reason, I was sure that wasn't the issue. I suppose it was a problem regarding sessions and locks, thank you again!